# Apps crash with "Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13"

Tags: crash, administrator, root, macbook-air, application-launch

I recently finished school but the IT department didn't unlock my computer. When I try to run certain apps (mostly certain games), they appear on the dock for 0.1 secs and then crash with out an error. I get two errors in the console:

```
no information back from LS about running process
```

and

```
Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13
```

Because this is an old school laptop, I believe terminal is locked from my access too. I have most administrator privileges (including installing apps and such).

Is there any way I could unlock my computer fully and fix this?

Comment: Is this on a Mac?

Comment: Yes, macbook air